# Making SQL Server the Persistence Provider in Thingworx

Tags: sql-server, thingworx

I am trying to make SQL Server 2014 my data persistence provider as per the instructions provided at http://support.ptc.com/cs/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_6.5_hc/index.jspx?id=ConfiguringaPersistenceProviderEntity&action=…

but unfortunately, I am not able to do so. I get an error message (please see attached screenshot). How can I solve this error?

Also when the instructions say import the `PersistenceProvider` package what exactly the instructions mean by that?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvxwg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add an extra Persistence Provider, since the installation package already made MSSQL as the default persistence provider while installation.